# How do I hard reset/factory reset my Supersonic SC-74JB 7-inch tablet with no physical volume button on?

Tags: factory-reset, hard-reset

I forgot the security password to get into my Supersonic (SC-74JB) 7-inch tablet that you need after you turn on the tablet. It doesn't have a physical volume button.

How do I hard reset/factory reset it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled usb debugging, in ADB shell type `reboot recovery` to boot to your recovery.